# Modify values of array columns

Tags: pyspark

I have two columns in a `df` and I want to transform some of their values based on some conditions. These columns are outcomes of `collect_set` `aggregations` so I have the option to apply some transformation beforehand without needing to explode again.

More specifically let's say the Dataframe looks like this table:

```
df = [
 (1,["0","1","2"],["10"]),
 (2,["0"],["20"]),
 (3,["3"],[null])
]
```

I want to transform it so:

1. if arr1 column has more than 1 elements, remove the '0' if it exists. if '0' is the only element then keep it.
2. if arr2 is has no elements, then pass a default value to it.

I tried to apply `size(col1)` to these columns but I am getting a `Column not iterable error`. `exploding` again the arrays and `collecting` their `sets` their options is really not an option to me for performance reasons so I have to either be creative beforehand or apply the transformations somehow directly to the arrays but in a cost efficient way.

That being said, the wished outcome will be:

```
df = [
 (1,["1","2"],["10"]),
 (2,["0"],["20"]),
 (3,["3"],["default_value"])
]
```

ordering is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **`size,higher`** order array functions to filter out the 0 from array elements without exploding.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,["0","1","2"],["10"]),(2,["0"],["20"]),(3,["3"],[None])],['id','arr','arr1'])
df.withColumn('arr',when(size(col("arr"))>1,expr("filter(arr, x -> x != 0)")).otherwise(col("arr"))).show(10,False)
#+---+------+------+
#|id |arr   |arr1  |
#+---+------+------+
#|1  |[1, 2]|[10]  |
#|2  |[0]   |[20]  |
#|3  |[3]   |[null]|
#+---+------+------+
```

Comment: that worked, thanks. I was trying something similar with the difference that I used array_remove() but it wasn't that handy